# Correct GAMM function for binary dependent variable

Tags: r, logistic, mgcv

I am looking for help for how to implement a correct syntax for my Generalized mixed effect model.

I have data for 4 independent transects set along an altitudinal gradient. I placed, at several locations along each transect, a prey specimen and recorded after a while whether or not the prey had been eaten.
I'm now looking to implement a model to test whether the probability of being eaten is dependent on altitude, while accounting for the fact that there are 4 different transects (considered to be 4 replicates). I don't want to make any a priori assumption whether or not there is a linear trend across altitude. I therefore assume this calls for a GAMM using the mgcv R package (I am an R user)? So far, I have come up with this syntax:

```
gamm(Eaten ~ s(Altitude, bs = "tp"), random=list(Transect_ID=~1),family="binomial",data=d)
```

I'm not sure whether this is the right syntax though because the y-axis does not show a binary axis, but rather a continuous axis with even negative values (although there are only 0's and 1's). This is strange given that 'Eaten' is a binary factor. In other words, the dependent variable is either only 0 or 1, with discrete values. I find the plots (see below) of the model outputs somewhat strange because the trend lines inferred by the models drop below 0 and go above 1, although these values are not possible theoretically.

Could you please verify the syntax of the model?

I also ran a `gam()` instead of a `gamm()` as suggested, but the model output is somewhat different. How can this be explained?

Plots of the results using either gamm() or gam()

[image]

**The summary stats of the two models**

**gam()**

```
Formula: Eaten ~ s(altitude, bs = "tp") + s(Transect_ID, bs = "re")    
Family: binomial    
Link function: logit 
s(altitude) efd = 3.761; Ref.df = 4.608; F = 8.495; p-value = 0.11232
s(Transect_ID) efd = 3.139; Ref.d = 4.000; F = 13.417; p-value = 0.00182
R-sq.(adj) = 0.267
Deviance explained = 26.9%
n = 92
```

**gamm()**

```
Formula: Eaten ~ s(altitude, bs = "tp")
Random Effect: Tansect_ID
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 
s(altitude) efd= 2.591; Ref.df = 2.591; F = 0.995; p-value= 0.231
R-sq.(adj) = 0.0749
n = 92
```

Both, the R2 as well as the (partial) effect of 'altitude', are different between the models.

Comment: The y-axis of what? ... If you are plotting the curves after fitting then you are likely looking at the effect of Altitude on Eaten. ps your syntax looks fine but i think you can also fit this with      gam(Eaten ~ s(Altitude, bs = "tp") + s(Transect_ID, bs="re"), family="binomial",data=d)

Comment: Thank you user20650 for your insights. I have added the plots as well as the gam() as you have suggested (see above). Also, I'm happy if this post gets moved to the stats site. I don't know how to achieve this myself though.

Comment: Thanks for your update. We (other users) should normally be able to move this to the stats site but there have not been any other votes to move it so it might take a while. So you could either flag your question and ask a mod to move it, or you could delete it and repost over there.

Comment: ps how many groups do you have ... the last plot suggests five?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to mention this, but I thought it's not all that relevant for my questions. It's actually 6 groups in this particular analysis. On the plot one can only see 5 points because 2 are perfectly overlapping, I assume.

Comment: okay, thanks. It may/may not be relevant but variance components can't be estimated well for a mall number of groups so perhaps it could explain small differences between the models. (althougth estimated smooths look v. similar)

Comment: I checked again, it's indeed only 5 groups – one of the 6 initial ones drops out because of no data. So at least this makes sense.

Comment: I would still be glad to receive some answers for:
(1) Why does the GAM and GAMM give me such different answers (particularly with regards to R2 and the significance of effects)? For my specific question, which of the two models would you recommend taking and why?
(2) How should I interpret (and visualize) my output from these models? Particularly, the dependent variable is binary in my case (Eaten), so it can only be either '0' or '1'. How is it possible that the model-inferred functions drop below a value of 0? Please see the plots above.

Comment: @8armed ; it may be worth editing your question to add these clarification - this will also nudge your question to the recently active list.